# How would I get these ID's of a specific genre in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very much a beginner at using XSLT and I have only recently begun learning it. I am having trouble with trying to print a certain value to display in HTML format based on the XML file below. Essentially I want the HTML page created by the XSL file to display all of the book ID's from **only** the Fantasy genre, to which they include 'bk102, bk102, bk104, and bk105'. I have tried myself for a while but honestly am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be widely appreciated, sorry for the trouble and thank you in advance.

XML File

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "books3.xsl"?>
<catalog>
   <book id = "bk101">
        <author> Gambardella, Matthew </author>
        <title> XML Developer's Guide </title>
        <genre> Computer </genre>
        <price> 44.95 </price>
        <publish>
            <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>
            <publisher> Wiley </publisher>
        </publish>
        <description> An in-depth look at creating applications with XML. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk102">
        <author> Ralls, Kim </author>
        <title> Midnight Rain </title>
        <genre> Fantasy </genre>
        <price> 5.95 </price>
        <publish>
            <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>
            <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
        </publish>
        <description> A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk103">
        <author> Corets, Eva </author>
        <title> Maeve Ascendant </title>
        <genre> Fantasy </genre>
        <price> 5.95 </price>
        <publish>
            <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date> 
            <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
        </publish>
        <description> After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk104">
        <author> Corets, Eva </author>
        <title> Oberon's Legacy </title>
        <genre> Fantasy </genre>
        <price> 5.95 </price>
        <publish>
            <publish_date> 2001 </publish_date> 
            <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
        </publish>
        <outOfPrint/>
        <description> In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve Ascendant. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk105">
         <author> Corets, Eva </author>
         <title> The Sundered Grail </title>
         <genre> Fantasy </genre>
         <price> 5.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2002 </publish_date>    
             <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
         </publish>
         <description> The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, battle one another for control of England. Sequel to Oberon's Legacy. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk106">
         <author> Randall, Cynthia </author>
         <title> Lover Birds </title>
         <genre> Romance </genre>
         <price> 4.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>    
             <publisher> Whitehouse </publisher>
         </publish>
         <description> When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk107">
         <author> Thurman, Paula </author>
         <title> Splish Splash </title>
         <genre> Romance </genre>
         <price> 4.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>    
             <publisher> Whitehouse </publisher>
         </publish>
         <description> A deep sea diver finds true love twenty thousand leagues beneath the sea. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk108">
         <author> Knorr, Stefan </author>
         <title> Creepy Crawlies </title>
         <genre> Horror </genre>
         <price> 4.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>    
         <publisher> Wiley </publisher>
         </publish>
         <outOfPrint/>
         <description> An anthology of horror stories about roaches,centipedes, scorpions  and other insects. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk109">
         <author> Kress, Peter </author>
         <title> Paradox Lost </title>
         <genre> Science Fiction </genre>
         <price> 6.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>    
             <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
         </publish>
         <description> After an inadvertant trip through a HeisenbergUncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems of being quantum. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk110">
         <author> O'Brien, Tim </author>
         <title> Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible </title>
         <genre> Computer </genre>
         <price> 36.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>    
             <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
         </publish>
         <description> Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk111">
         <author> O'Brien, Tim </author>
         <title> MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide </title>
         <genre> Computer </genre>
         <price> 36.95 </price>
         <publish>
             <publish_date> 2000 </publish_date>    
             <publisher> Penguin </publisher>
         </publish>
         <outOfPrint/>
         <description> The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, SAX and more. </description>
   </book>
   <book id = "bk112">
         <author> Galos, Mike </author>
         <title> Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide </title>
         <genre> Computer </genre>
         <price> 49.95 </price>
         <publish>
            <publish_date> 2001 </publish_date> 
            <publisher> Wiley </publisher>
         </publish>
         <description> Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are integrated into a comprehensive development environment. </description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

XSLT File

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">
<xsl:output method = "html"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">
<html>
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select = "catalog/book">

        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show the expected output.

Comment: I would like to output to a HTML file or browser displaying the following:

Comment: bk102 bk103 bk104 bk105

Comment: So just to print the ID's of the books that are of the Fantasy genre

Comment: Your output method is HTML. Please the exact expected output **as HTML code** to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="book[normalize-space(genre)='Fantasy']">
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, thank you for clearing that up :)